# Javascript cookie values not being stored in single session

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this **shop** page that uses a javascript cookie to store the contents of the visitor's shopping cart.

The cookie is stored like so:

```
document.cookie=products[x].id + "=" + products[x].qty;
```

And the values are stored correctly with product code and quantity.

```
 Name        Value
-----------|--------
 PRODUCT1  | 0
 PRODUCT2  | 1
 PRODUCT3  | 2
```

However, once the visitor has checked out and completed the shopping flow, there is a **confirmation** page that resets the values of the cart:

```
for (x in products) document.cookie=products[x].id + "=" + 0;
```

The values in the cookie are all zero as expected. The problem occurs when navigating back to the **shop** page where the cookie suddenly has the inital values and the cart is not empty.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: you should probably avoid manually manipulating `document.cookie`... use a library to perform cookie CRUD and save yourself future headaches. e.g. https://code.google.com/p/cookies/

Comment: I think you should expect that behavior. What if it were not a confirmation page but a pop-up instead?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not overwriting your original cookie but creating a new one. You have to be in the exact same domain (www.greener.xyz / shop.greener.xyz). You must also have the same protocol (http / https).